# How to store handler in objective c model class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, compiler-errors, closures

I have AppDelegate.m in my iOS/Objective-C project,

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

}
```

I need to store both `userInfo` and `completionHandler` in a model class for later use. Hence I tried to make a model like,

```
@interface MyNotification: NSObject
@property (copy) NSDictionary* userInfo ;
@property (copy) (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result)) completionHandler;
@end

@implementation MyNotification
@end
```

Thats giving me compiler error. How can I store both parameters in a model for later use?

[image]

Comment: "Thats giving me compiler error. " What error?

Comment: @Larme updated my post with error. Please check.

Comment: In Objective-C, they are called "Blocks". You might be looking for that: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com There is a Swift version https://fuckingclosuresyntax.com

Comment: @Larme is it possible to store the block and fire later in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
@property (copy) void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result);
```

And I would suggest adding `nonatomic` to your property declarations too.

Comment: Just an off topic, does it even work when I store push handler and call it after sometimes? any better idea? Background: I need to save the push userInfo for later use? When push is received my db is not ready due to data protection unavailable and hence I need to store the push so that I can fire handler after protected data becomes available. Is it even possible to store handler and fire it later?

Comment: Your question was apparently about a compiler error. So was my answer. If my answer told you correctly how to fix the compiler error, please accept it.

Comment: Thats why added a prefix `off-topic`. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: However, my title was not regarding purly compilers error. @matt